# Is there any replacement for kafka connect kinesis?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to find the api that connects kinesis to kafka.
The API listed on the [kafka connecter website](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) is dead.

see https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-kinesis

Any suggested replacement?

Comment: I've noticed that all his connectors are either now in a private github or deleted... Not sure what's going on

Comment: yea..not sure either. Hope everything is well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This connector will be included in the Confluent Enterprise connector program, and will be available for download soon from https://confluent.io

Comment: thanks for the note! do you know around when will that happen?

Comment: Will support still be offered to those that have cloned the code when it was on Github?